# Does physical prediction depend on the topologies that we put in the space of smooth section of a vector bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, topology, foundations

In the artice [Properties of field functionals and characterization of local functionals](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01654120v3/document), we have

> Let $M$ be a manifold and $B \rightarrow M$ be a smooth vector bundle of $\operatorname{rank} r$ over $M$ with projection $\pi$. Let $E=\Gamma(M, B)$ be the space of smooth sections of $B$ equipped with the following topology: ${ }^{28}$
> Definition II.1. The topology on $\Gamma(M, B)$ is defined as follows. Choose a chart $\left(U_{\alpha}, \psi_{\alpha}\right)_{\alpha}$ and a trivialization map $\Phi_{\alpha}: \pi^{-1}\left(U_{\alpha}\right) \rightarrow \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^{r}$, where $\Omega$ is a fixed open set in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Then the map $\Phi_{\alpha}$ allows us to identify $\Gamma\left(U_{\alpha}, B\right)$ with $C^{\infty}\left(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{r}\right)$ by $\Phi_{\alpha}: \pi^{-1} U_{\alpha} \rightarrow \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^{d}$ such that
> $$
> \Phi_{\alpha}(x, s(x))=\left(\psi_{\alpha}(x), K_{\alpha}(s)\left(\psi_{\alpha}(x)\right)\right),
> $$
> where
> $$
> K_{\alpha}: s \in \Gamma\left(U_{\alpha}, B\right) \mapsto K_{\alpha}(s) \in C^{\infty}\left(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{r}\right) .
> $$
> The topology on $\Gamma(M, B)$ is the weakest topology making all the maps $K_{\alpha}$ continuous.

Now, in the article [Green-hyperbolic operators on globally hyperbolic spacetimes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0738), they have

> We denote the space of smooth sections of $E$ by $C^{\infty}(M, E) .$ Any connection $\nabla$ on $E$ induces, together with the Levi-Civita connection on $T^{*} M$, a connection on $T^{*} M^{\otimes \ell} \otimes E$ for any $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$. For any $f \in C^{\infty}(M, E)$, the $\ell^{\text {th }}$ covariant derivative $\nabla^{\ell} f:=$ $\nabla \ldots \nabla \nabla f$ is a smooth section of $T^{*} M^{\otimes \ell} \otimes E .$
> For any compact subset $K \subset M$, any $m \in \mathbb{N}$, any connection $\nabla$ on $E$ and any auxiliary norms $|\cdot|$ on $T^{*} M^{\otimes \ell} \otimes E$ we define the semi-norm
> $$
> \|f\|_{K, m, \nabla,|\cdot|}:=\max _{\ell=0, \cdots, m} \max _{x \in K}\left|\nabla^{\ell} f(x)\right|
> $$
> for $f \in C^{\infty}(M, E) .$ By compactness of $K$, different choices of $\nabla$ and $|\cdot|$ lead to equivalent

With this family of seminorms we can define a [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) (i.e. set of open sets) in this space of smooth section of this vector bundle.

So these two articles define two different topologies in the space of smooth section of a vector bundle. With these topologies, we can define objects like distributions, derivatives etc. that we use to make a physical prediction.

My question is: Does physical prediction depend on the topology that we put in the space of smooth section of a vector bundle?

Comment: I do not understand the question. If you use a topology that does not make $M$ into a manifold, you basically cannot do calculus on $M$, how are you going to obtain "predictions" at all?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I mean another topology  $\tau'$ that makes $M$ into another manifold with the same dimension

Comment: I'm not sure what you're imagining here: Can you exhibit a simple example? For instance, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are bijective as sets, so it's just "choice of topology" that makes a set with the cardinality of the continuum into $\mathbb{R}$ as opposed to $\mathbb{R}^2$ as manifolds. But all physical predictions are based on formulae that use calculus, i.e. presuppose a (smooth) manifold structure. How do you think you can compare "predictions" here?

Comment: @ACuriousMind  I will edit my question

Comment: I believe the idea is, for example, how different physics in $\mathbb{R}^4$ spacetime is from, e.g., Physics in $\mathbb{T}^4$ (torus) spacetime, right?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean but  I will edit my question

Comment: @ACuriousMind I edited my question

Comment: In string theory, using another manifold for the fibre bundles leads to different predictions.

Comment: How are the topologies you describe used in predictions?